# How to use PHP/jQuery to realize a unique user on load?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a webpage that stores the user ID of someone who clicks a button on the page.  Once the button is clicked, that user needs to be able to see content (just another button) that only that user can see. Other users on that page won't be able to see that button.

The problem I'm having is I don't know how to use that unique user ID, which is superglobal,  to recognize on load what the user ID is, and how to execute if its the correct user, show the otherwise hidden inputs.

Comment: how are you currently storing the user ID of who clicked the button?

Comment: Using jQuery to send it over to a hidden span when the button is clicked.

Comment: As with anything client side, your method appears to be vulnerable to spoofing.  What happens when a user, via dev tools, simply changes that value to something else?

Comment: What would you recommend? I also have the user ID being ajax'd over and stored in a mysql db. I don't think spoofing is a large concern for this webpage.

Comment: I would recommend you do the user-session verification server-side.  Eg: Render the div based only on user id via php, then when the user clicks the button, the page being retrieved via ajax also has a session declared.  Verification is done on that page before the response is sent back.

Comment: @kevin have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is same problem that arised to me

You have two option to solve this problem

1. use a PHP globals like `$_COOKIE[]` or `$_SESSION{]`; To store the id of that user
2. or you can use a database field of array type.It will store the value of button clicked by a particular user(using a database will more efficient because you can use it any time and it do not expires )